# In-app search in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone 8.1. I have to implement "Search" functionality wherein I have to search the text file and update list view in my app. Also I have noticed the searchbox and searchresultspage in windows Store 8.1 apps but it's not available on windows phone 8.1. Any idea how shall I do it?

Update: (added code)

```
public List<DataArticle> matchedarticles { get; set; }

 private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var queryText = e.NavigationParameter as String;
        var folders = await MHDataSource.GetFoldersAsync();

        foreach(var folder in folders)
        {

            var art = folder.Articles.Where(
                article => article.Title.IndexOf(
                    queryText,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
            matchedarticles = art.ToList();
        }
       this.defaultViewModel["Results"] = matchedarticles;

    }
```

How can I retrieve the articles and assign it to the list(matchedarticles) based on the querytext??

Comment: I have a local json file which is similar to the SampleData.json in hub app templates. The search query has to be matched with the Title and all the items, who have search query in their titles needs to be returned.

Comment: Can you put some more information to your question nad some code? You want to deserialize your json file first, or just search it as text file?

Comment: I have added the code. There is a datasouce class which parses the JSON and puts it inside a class. All i need to know is to access the class and fetch items based on the querytext

Comment: I'm not sure how the rest of the code looks like, but from this above I suspect that you will see only results for last folder in folders: `matchedarticles = art.ToList();` - every time you are setting a new list. Maybe it should be: `matchedarticles.AddRange(art.ToList());`?